# Why does the Ebay application automatically startup at boot?

Tags: boot, logging

I can't find a good reason that this application must always be running on my phone. However, it starts at boot and I'm constantly getting error traces in Logcat about the Ebay application.

Why does this application start at boot?

Comment: because it was written that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it starts because that's how dev coded it.

You can try programs like [startup manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=imoblife.startupmanager&hl=en) that will kill the program once it starts.

Comment: Right, which to me is a huge mistake. If I use the application once a month, why would I want it in the background clogging up GC and spewing errors 24/7? I'll have to give some feedback.